# Calculating Pair Correlation Function with Periodic BCs

Tags: spatial, particles

### 1. PCF or RDF?

My first (very basic) question: is the pair correlation function the same as the radial distribution function? This [article](https://shocksolution.com/microfluidics-and-biotechnology/calculating-the-pair-correlation-function-in-python/#:%7E:text=The%20pair%20correlation%20function%2C%20also,in%20a%20three%2Ddimensional%20space.) suggests so, but I'd appreciate confirmation of that.

### 2. Example

I'm trying to calculate the pair correlation function for a random packing of discs with periodic boundary conditions. Let's say I have the following configuration of discs of radius 1. Following the procedure outlined [here](http://www.physics.emory.edu/faculty/weeks/idl/gofr2.html), I choose a particle for consideration, let's say the particle in grey.

[image]

Now, let's say I let r=4 and dr=1 and I'll count all of the other disc centers that are particles that are a distance between 4 and 5 from this grey disc. This is where I'm unsure. As in the picture below, do I include "boundary discs" that are off the edge of my original domain? As in, should I count 6 discs here?

The next step then is to divide this count by N, the total number of discs. Should I take N to be 10, as in the top picture? Or 16, as in the bottom picture?

[image]

### 3. Clarification on PCF Formula

I believe that the correct formula for the pair correlation function is:
[image]

Is this correct? What does the delta function in this formula represent?

Answer (score 0):

Q1: I'm not sure either! But for sure they are closely related. I prefer "g(r) = RDF" to judge the distribution since it's a normalized quantity (i.e. g(r) = 1 corresponds to a uniform distribution), so you can compare different distributions no matter how many samples you have in the domain.

Q2: This is a tricky question! First, let's say your domain is not periodic, so you have walls/boundaries. What happens is even if you have a uniform distribution (so we expect g = 1) everywhere, g(r) will be a function decreasing from 1 (small r) to 0 (large r). This is because for the discs whose distances to the walls are less than the scanning radius, there are *disc-free* regions outside the boundaries where a neighboring disc *never* exists. Therefore, g → 0 as r increases.

Now let's switch to your case: periodic domains. If we are to judge the distribution in the domain with no influence from the walls/boundaries (for example, when we have a sample distribution from a larger domain), the remedy is to periodically repeat the distribution in the domain. In such a case, an ideal uniform distribution would result in g(r) = 1 for all r. Since the scanning radius is limited (0 < r < scan_rad), in order to periodically extend the domain, we only need to repeat the parts (discs) within a distance of scanning radius next to the boundaries. This is as if we have infinitely many domains next to the current one from all eight cardinal directions. After doing so, you won't have any disc-free region around the discs close to the boundaries.

However, you need to be careful with counting the pairs inside the main domain and those in the repeated (outside the) domain. In the figure you attached, within the considered shell 4 < r < 5 around the grey disc, there are 5 neighbors *inside* the domain and only 1 neighbor *outside* the domain. So we have already counted 6 pairs in the shell. Reciprocally, the grey disc is within the same shell for those 5 neighbors but we *never* count pairs for the discs outside the domain! So, there are 6 + 5 = 11 pairs in this shell which must be divided by 2 as we counted the pairs twice. This leaves us with 5.5 pairs in this shell that involves the grey disc (we need to consider other discs as well). Of course when you write a code you are smart enough not to double-count. In that case, the trick is to count 1 pair in the related shells when both discs are inside the domain and count 0.5 when one disc is outside the (in the repeated) domain.

Regarding your next question, I'm not sure why there is division by N. As I mentioned, I prefer g(r) as RDF in which the pairs are divided by the pair density. Let's return to this later.

Q3: I cannot confirm this definition but it looks good to me. Delta is a function whose value is 1 at x = 0 but 0 for all other x. So, delta(r - r_ij) = 1 when r = r_ij. Also, note that this seems to be a 3D definition not applicable to your 2D case since 4πr²dr is the volume of a spherical shell at r. However, you're considering ring shells with the area 2πrdr.

Note: 2D RDF (in my view) is defined as the number density of pairs separated at r divided by the number density of all pairs in the domain. In other words:
g(r) = ( n(r) / s_ring ) / ( npair / s_domain )
n(r): number of discs whose center distances fall in the ring between circles of radii r - eps < distance < r + eps
s_ring: area of the ring = π(r+eps)² - π(r-eps)²
npair: total number of pairs in the domain = N*(N-1)/2 where N is the number of discs
s_domain: domain area